# Error saving file

Tags: permissions, geany

I use Geany to edit my bash scripts in my bin directory.

When I try to save them, I get

```
Error saving file. Operation not permitted.

File on disk may be truncated.
```

I can save them if I use Save As?

I tried

```
andy7_~/bin$ sudo chown -R andy:  /home/andy/bin/
chown: changing ownership of '/home/andy/bin/Seamonkey_Startup_Time.sh': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/home/andy/bin/Find_File.sh': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of '/home/andy/bin/Relax_Music.sh': Operation not permitted
andy7_~/bin$ ll
total 376
drwxrwxr-x  2 andy andy  4096 Jul 23 14:16 ./
drwxr-xr-x 36 andy andy  4096 Jul 23 14:12 ../
-rwxrwxr-x  1 andy root    64 Jan 22 22:19 30_VOL.sh*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 andy root    59 Dec 22  2017 4kYouTube2_Mp3.sh*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 andy root    92 Jan 22 22:23 50_Percent_VOL.sh*
-rwxrwxr-x  1 andy andy    92 Jul 14 12:41 70_Percent_VOL.sh*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 andy root  1767 May 15  2017 arrange_dt.py*
-rwxrwxr-x  1 andy andy  2451 Jul 20 15:57 Backup_18.04_AMD.sh*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 andy root  2412 Jul 13 01:46 Backup_AMD.sh*
-rwxrwxr-x  1 andy andy   117 Jul 13 18:32 Bin_Dir.sh*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 andy root    40 Jul 19 13:14 Blank.sh*
-rwxrwxr-x  1 andy andy    44 Jul 13 15:42 boot.sh*
-rwxrwxr-x  1 andy root   709 Jul 17 11:04 Browser_Startup_Time.sh*
```

Comment: The `ll` output shows many files with different permissions, so which one(s) in particular are giving you problems?

Comment: -rwxrwxr-x  1 andy andy   195 Jul 21 10:05 Relax_Music.sh* is one example.

Comment: `Relax_Music.sh` isn't in the `ll` output. Maybe the disk is dying.

Comment: Wait, did you truncate the `ll` output?

Comment: Yes. I may have to restore a Clonezilla image. I don't understand how all of a sudden I have permission issues?

Comment: Run my `pathlld` script on the file you have trouble with. https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld.git - Bash script to answer "Why can't I read/write that file?"

Comment: andy7_~/bin$ sudo ./pathlld Relax_Music.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 andy andy 140 Jul 19 11:16 Relax_Music.sh